# Does free SPSS 16 actually exist?

Tags: spss, software

My mother heard about free SPSS 16 and gave me the task of finding a safe download of it. However, I can't find *any* site (except torrents) that actually have it available, they all seem to use SPSS 16 as a bait and switch to take you to the page with the latest version.

Comment: There's [PSPP](http://www.gnu.org/software/pspp/).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about software distribution.

Answer (score 2):

SPSS isn't free, so you won't find a legal version of SPSS 16 that's free. There is a free, open-source alternative to SPSS, called [PSPP](http://www.gnu.org/software/pspp/). PSPP is designed to look like SPSS, though it still has fewer functions available than SPSS.

Comment: I had that feeling.

Comment: @AndyBlankertz I forgot to mention that one bonus is that PSPP can open SPSS data files (.sav) directly... if that's any consolation to your mother.